# Not able to stop processing form when image file has not been chosen

Tags: php, file-upload, error-handling

I have a form that I use to submit a new post with images in. I don't want the post to proceed to submitting data to the server and database if the user has not chosen an image to upload. At the moment everything I try is letting the code continue to processing the form.

Heres some of my code:

```
//check if the submit button has been clicked
        if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

            //validate the title and description
            $title = validate_title($_POST['title']);
            $desc = validate_desc($_POST['desc']);

            //Get other posted variables
            $cat = $_POST['cat'];
            $year = $_POST['year'];

            if($title && $desc != false){

                //check if an image has been submitted
                if( $_FILES['files']['name'] != ""){...
```

I have also tried using the following methods, but neither stop the code when no file has been selected:

```
if( $_FILES['files']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){...

if( $_FILES['files']['name'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){...
```

Comment: Checking for a name should work. var_dump($_FILES) right before you check to see what you have.

Comment: I get this: array(1) { ["files"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "d3beta1.png" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(45) "C:\Users\chris\AppData\Local\Temp\php6B29.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1728245) } } }

Comment: Even when I select an image to upload it gives me the error, also using:

Comment: "if((!empty($_FILES["files"])) && ($_FILES['files']['error'] == 0)) {"

Comment: You are missing an index. if ($_FILES['files']['name'][0] != "")

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your file input name is `files[]`, in this case $_FILES["files"]["name"] will be an array, to check if a user supplied an image for upload try,

```
foreach ($_FILES['files']["error"] as $index => $error){
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
        //no file was uploaded in $index`th file input 
    }
    else{
        //other checks and process $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$index]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `bool is_uploaded_file ( string $filename )`.

Example, where user_file is the sub-array of your file upload:

```
<?php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
{
   // Success, file uploaded
}
else
{
   // Error, no file, invalid file, etc.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is the best process to handle all uploaded files like:

```
    // allowed extensions
$extensions = array('.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg','.PNG', '.GIF', '.JPG', '.JPEG');

        if((!empty($_FILES["files"])) && ($_FILES['files']['error'] == 0)) {

            // check extension
            $extension = strrchr($_FILES['files']['name'], '.');
            if (!in_array($extension, $extensions)) {
                echo 'wrong file format, alowed only .png , .gif, .jpg, .jpeg';
            } else {
                // get file size
                $filesize = $_FILES['files']['size'];

                // check filesize
                if($filesize > $maxlimit){ 
                    echo "File size is too big.";
                } else if($filesize < 1){ 
                    echo "File size is empty.";
                } else {

                    // temporary file
                    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: $extensions array is not fixed

Comment: For some reason this "if((!empty($_FILES["files"])) && ($_FILES['files']['error'] == 0)) {" returns false for me even when i select a file.

Comment: you've since changed the syntax of the array, form one long string.

Comment: @crm Have you set maximum file size limit? $maxlimit = 9048576; And what is the name of field form field?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user not to be able to send any request when he has not selected any images, you can make it by java script client-side. User will get an error when a form submit is about to begin. But keep in mind, users can work round this validation easily. There is no way to do it client-side and it is reliable. It is better to check it server-side as the others have answered.